# Java embedded windows XP

Tags: c#, java, windows-xp, embedded

I have an java application that I want to use on a Windows XP Embedded computer, but the Java SE Embedded says that it would require royalties. Would the regular Java SE work in Windows XP Embedded, and would it require royalties?

If not, would it be free to use C# and .net?

I haven't been able to find anything about royalties for Java SE (not embedded), C# and .net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java SE Embedded](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/embedded/overview/getstarted/index.html) is for embedded devices like e-Readers or cell phones.

Windows XP Embedded should be able to run normal editions of Java.
It can certainly run .Net code, free of charge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:). Do you know if normal editions of java would require royalties on windows XP embedded?

Comment: You just need to make sure your XPEmbedded build contains the JRE, which should be an option on the build configuration. You shouldn't need to pay anything extra for it.

Comment: @Alle: I strongly assume not.

Comment: @Alle: The use of "normal" editions of Oracle Java in embedded systems is prohibited. Read the JRE Binary License.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have installed proper java SE? Try to download install java SE for windows Embedded from the following link.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/embedded-jsp-135769.html

Thanks
Deepak